# How to check if the google translator extension is active or not in the browser using angular?

Tags: angular, browser

I need to check if the google translator extension is active or not in the browser using angular

i tried with "((window as any)['google'] && (window as any)['google']['translate'])" this code but this always returns only false even after we change the extension status in our browser.

I tried to update the node and angular version also but could not get the desired result.